# Vue-router How to come back to a specific section of the home page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have ci-urrently a home page with many sections taht the user can access by scrolling or from a navbar menu-1. In this menu there is also a "Plus" button to request additional pages from the router

All pages called from a router have a navbar menu-2 to call other pages from the router or go back to the home page

It"s working fine...

but I would like to be able from this pages to go back to a specific section  of the home page;..

I tried to use :

```
              <div class="navbar-text">
              <!-- Button trigger modal-->
              <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="dropbtn">PLUS...</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a @click="$router.push('/home#about-us')">ABOUT US</a>
                      <a @click="$router.push('/home#memberships')">MEMBERSHIPS</a>
                      <a @click="$router.push('/hoem#events')">EVENTS</a>
                      <a @click="$router.push('/home#portfolio')">PORTFOLIO</a>
                      <a @click="$router.push('/home#leaders')">LEADERS</a>
                      <a @click="$router.push('/home#contact')">CONTACT</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

but no way .. I'm always back to the top of the home page ...

any trick ? thanks for feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Vue Router - Scroll Behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) from the docs:

> When using client-side routing, we may want to scroll to top when navigating to a new route, or preserve the scrolling position of history entries just like real page reload does. vue-router allows you to achieve these and even better, allows you to completely customize the scroll behavior on route navigation.

Specially the code before Async Scrolling section

Comment: @mohd-ph thanks for your feedback. I read this chapter about scroll behavior, I am using it in  maanaging  #routing in my home page w multiple sections ( get all the infos in the to parameter ).  However in my case , I am call ing the router from another page ( not inside the home page) so the scrollBehavior is not executed at all...

Comment: Got it to run .. .. updated my scrollBehavior  thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

updated the scrollBehavior in my router index.js

```
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {selector: to.hash}
    } else if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, You can try this way

In router js file

```
scrollBehavior(to: any, from: any, savedPosition: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ x: 0, y: 0 });
      }, 480);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but the above methods didn't really work very well for me. I had to add an extra tweek to wait for all records to be loaded from the db before attempting the scroll to savedposition.

```
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (to.hash) {
          return resolve({ selector: to.hash });
        } else if (savedPosition) {
          return resolve(savedPosition);
        } else {
          resolve(document.getElementById("app").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" }));
        }
      }, 1200);
    });
```

},